# Canonical livepatch error

Tags: 22.04

I am getting failed to start canonical-livepatch.service after every time I am trying to reboot my PC. It just happened after my casual update. No booting up process is there. Just hung there

Comment: "*It just happened after my manual update*:" Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1483137/edit) to explain your "manual update"

Comment: "casual update" is just as unhelpful as "manual update".  Explain what you mean

Comment: I just opened my PC and was doing my work after that , I updated my packages through terminal and rebooted , it took some time and was hanged for 2 minutes then it auto-rebooted, after that the problem is persisting.